# How to calculate Actual Sales per day using DAX

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, tabular, dax, msbi

I'm trying to get Actual Sales per day using DAX howver I can't able to get the Actual Sales Per Day using DAX Expression.

[image]

I'm using below DAX to calculate Total No. of days.

b:=CALCULATE(COUNT(DimDate[Date]),DimDate[CY_Year]=YEAR(TODAY()),USERELATIONSHIP(Fact_Sales[Doc_Date],DimDate[Date]))

Please provide the correct formula.

Comment: Please post your formulas for a and b

Comment: I already posted formula for b and a is nothing but sum of Sales Amount.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [a] is a measure in the Data Model then you just create a new measure for Actual Sales Per Day as follows:

```
c :=
[a] / [b]
```

If [a] is not already a measure in the Data Model then create it first as follows:

```
a :=
SUM ( [SalesAmount] )
```